# Magento 1.9.0.1 add a product to the cart by URL from external site?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, url, form-key

I need to add multiple products from an external site to a Magento store. The stores sells cake decorations and they wan't to create recipes in their Wordpress blog, and with a simple press of a button all the ingredients to be added to the cart in Magento. I found in other questions that in order for this to work we need a formkey, but how can I generate the form key from outside of Magento?